# Cross-origin request

Tags: php, ajax, cors

Help me on this please I'm calling a PHP file using XmlhttpRequest but the browser is showing cross-Origin Request blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.myurl.to (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). but the resource 'https://www.myurl.to' is not what I am calling. I don't know why it is working like that.

Comment: And what's the endpoint URL?

Comment: it might make sense to show us your actual code

Comment: `https://www.myurl.to'` **must** be what you are calling. You are either looking at the wrong piece of code or requesting something that gets an HTTP redirect response.

Comment: Oh I appreciate your help, I had lost my local files and I downloaded what I had online and it came with the .htaccess file which was redirecting my request on another url I deleted the file and it worked very fine. But it was a headache ...